# nav-pills hover background color change bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change default background color when I hover `nav-pills`'s `li` tag. How should I do? What is the bootstrap class for that I should change?

Comment: simply inspect the element in your browser console and you will be able to see the relevant styles affecting the element and then add overriding styles to your custom style.css

Comment: It's definitely pulling the style from somewhere - is the site live so I can view it?

Comment: nope it is not hosted yet. I didn't use anything other than bootstrap 3

Comment: just answered there- if it resolves your problem (which it should) I would appreciate that you mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working from the getbootstrap.com site code if you modify the values to whatever background color you want

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

and add to your custom css file you will be able to modify this element.

*note:* The `<li>` element isn't styled on `:hover`, rather it is the `<a>` element contained within it.

Comment: Hey, you have a typo: `background-color`.